# How to install winapi for lua

Tags: winapi, lua, installation

So, I'm at a complete loss on where to start and install. Can someone give me some directions or similar maybe a video at least to help me out. It will be much appreciated.

Comment: `luarocks install winapi` works just fine

Answer (score 0):

winapi module "comes" (if you compile it from source or download as a binary) as `winapi.dll`, so you can put it in any location that is being checked based on your `package.cpath` or `LUA_CPATH` settings.

Usually, if you do `require'winapi'` without the module being installed, you'll get a list of locations that Lua checks to find `winapi.dll` (and `winapi.lua`, but you can ignore those for this case). You can try putting `winapi.dll` next to your application script to see if this works (assuming it's the current folder).